# Changing bounds with integration using $u$ substitution

Tags: integration

I am trying to find the value of the following integral:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^5 x\sqrt{25 - x^2} dx
\end{equation}

I know that $u$ would be equal  to $25-x^2$ and $du$ would equal $-2xdx$. Then you would pull the $-1/2$ out front and then integrate $u$ to $\frac{2}{3}u^3/2$. I'm getting confused because the answer key changed the bounds to $25$ to $0$. Can someone please explain why the bounds changed?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the integration is now over $u$. When $x$ took the value $0$, now $u$ takes the value $25$ (Since $u=25-x^2$). When $x$ took the value $5$, $u$ takes the value $25-5^2=0$.

Comment: ok thank you. I completely forgot that you have to substitute the values back in